# How to open a preview image in Matlab full screen?

Tags: matlab, preview

I need to open several jpg files in Matlab from Mac "preview" using !open. I don't want to use "imread" but instead want to open directly from preview.

I need these images either become full screen (once opening) or all open on top of each other. Now they slide down. How can I do that?

Thanks